# Dynamic certificate usage with jmeter

Tags: ssl, passwords, certificate, jmeter

i am trying to use JMeter 2.11 to test some webapp.

I have a certain order of test cases, one of these is to download a unique server generated client certificate and also to obtain the password for that in my test plan.
both these steps are working, I get the `.pfx` or `.p12` file as well as I have the pw stored in a variable for later use.
But I did not find a way to use the certificate for later test steps ... I tried using the SSL manager, but this didn't work - and can't be what I need I guess, because I can only enter a cert pw when starting the whole test plan at start - but the password I get later on during execution.
Also I need to loop this whole process a few hundred times..

If you would have some hints for me how to use a downloaded certificate dynamically for each loop and provide the password within the loop, that would be just great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JMeter, almost anything can be done programatically. Beanshell is generally preferred where you can write java code directly, and interact with internal or external java classes.

JMeter has an SSLManager class, which is used to manage and manipulate the key store, so certificates can be loaded mid run and and the key store re-initialised. Notice there are some rules specific to JMeter, like keystore password must match the password used for the first key in the store, and only the first key in the store will be used. In your case you will need to make sure it is the first key that gets replaced each iteration, rather than just adding keys, which will not work.

http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/SSLManager.html